# Is possible to use CATextLayer in a c struct?

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, core-animation

I need to associate a tag with a CATextLayer so I thought this:

.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

typedef struct textLayerWithTag
{
    CATextLayer *textLayer;
    int tag;
}textLayerWithTag;
```

.m`

```
textLayerWithTag textLayer1;

textLayer1.tag = 0;
textLayer1.textLayer = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
textLayer1.textLayer.string = @"aaaa";
textLayer1.textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 10.f, 320.f, 32.f);

[self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer1.textLayer];`
```

But when I try to build it I have this error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATextLayer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-CATextLayer in StructViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas? :/

Comment: Have you include QuartzCore and CoreText frameworks in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't linking the QuartzCore and CoreText Frameworks to your project. Right click on the Frameworks Group in XCode and then do add->Existing Frameworks... Select QuartzCore and CoreText and you should be good to go!

Comment: Sure I just check it now and they are in the target :/

Comment: Glad to help, just be sure and select the answer :)

Comment: Nono Richard I wanted to say that I check and they are on it but I have always the error :/

Comment: Really? Same error... I don't think i deserve the check then.... Come into chat (I just enabled you to) and we can talk about it there...